# how to subtract values in excel such that the values has been assigned the same name?

Tags: excel

How to solve this case:

Suppose there are two columns having same text assigned with values then i need to subtract those values to get the result in a new cell

For eg: if james in cell a1 has been assigned value as 20 in cell b1 and also james in cell c2 has been assigned value as 40 in cell d2, then i need to get the result as (40-20=20) in a different cell such that while giving the formula the James in cell a1 and c2 has to be same and only there corresponding values get subtracted and not with any other cell.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I find it a little strange that you would be starting with C and subtracting A, but okay. If what you are doing is looking for a name in C and taking the number in the right column then subtracting that from the value to the right of the same name in A, then VLookup has you covered:

```
=VLOOKUP("james",C:D,2)-VLOOKUP("james",A:B,2)
```

Comment: then that means you do not have a cell in both A and C that are just "james".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a formula based on INDEX and MATCH, which doesn't require cells to be sorted (as VLOOKUP does):

=INDEX(B:B; MATCH("James";A:A;0)) - INDEX(D:D; MATCH("James";C:C;0))

If either A:A or C:C doesn't have a "James", then the formula will return #NA. You can avoid this by adding a conditional to check whether the match is valid.

For example, if column C might not contact "James", replace

INDEX(D:D; MATCH("James";C:C;0))

with:

IF(ISNA(MATCH("James";C:C;0)); 0; INDEX(D:D; MATCH("James";C:C;0)))

which will then return 0 if there is no James in column C, otherwise the corresponding value in column D will be returned.